# Automatically escape <'s and >'s

Tags: asp.net, html, css, visual-studio-2010, visual-web-developer-2010

I want to show text on a web page *without* having to remember to go over it and check if there are any `<`'s and `>`'s in it, so simply copying the text from, say, notepad to visual studio isn’t good.

So I tried "paste alternate" but it adds line breaks, and keeps the original fonts etc. All I want is the text itself.

Is there an automatic way - via CSS or Visual Studio perhaps?

Comment: It can be done on the server side. But I don't think it can be on the client

Comment: @CarlSaldanha OK. That's better than nothing. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex search+replace: `s/</&lt;/` and `s/>/&gt;/`

Comment: Don't need regEx. Simple string substitution will do.

Comment: +1. I'd rather have it completely automatic so that it checks for anything which might change the rendering. But this is actually a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer that uses jQuery.

Use the `.text()` function.

Will return all the text present in the HTML.

http://api.jquery.com/text/

For example `($('<p>test</p>').text());`

will produce `test`

**EDIT**

For string substitution you can try the javascript replace method. Call it on document load. It should solve the problem

```
str.replace(">","&gt;");
```

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately I need something else. To change `a > b` to `a &gt; b`.

Comment: @ispiro Misunderstood. Edit the answer.Something like above should do it :-)

Comment: That would be nice. However, it would be pretty tricky to get it to replace only in the selection instead of ruining the whole web-page.